# how to ffill a multi-index dataframe based on a first level mask

Tags: python, pandas, nan, missing-data

I have a multi-index dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
arrays = [['bar', 'baz','foo'],  range(4)]
tuples = list(product(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
multi_ind=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, len(tuples)), index=range(6), columns=index)
```

Some values are nans:

```
multi_ind.loc[3,('bar',2)]=np.nan
multi_ind.loc[3,('bar',3)]=np.nan
multi_ind.loc[4,('bar',1)]=np.nan
```

[image]

For `'bar'` I would like to fill all nans expect last, as described in:

[Forward fill all except last value in python pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388419/forward-fill-all-except-last-value-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

```
mask=multi_ind['bar']
last_valid_column_per_row = mask.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index,axis=1)
mask=mask.apply(lambda series:series[:int(last_valid_column_per_row.loc[series.name])].ffill(),axis=1)
```

Then I would like to `ffill()` also the other first levels (.e.g `baz`,`foo`), using the same logic as for bar (up to last valid index from `df['bar']`), and I would like to set a `nan` also any value which was still `nan` in `bar`

How to achieve that in an efficient way?

Now I am doing the following, but it is very slow...

```
df_as_dict={}
df=df.ffill(axis=1) # start by ffilling
for first_level,gr in df.groupby(level=0,axis=1):
    gr[first_level][(mask.isnull())]=np.nan # then remove the nans (they should be only at the end)
    df_as_dict[first_level]=gr[first_level]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code based on *last_valid_index* (in the indicated post) actually
fills *NaN* along the given axis:

- without **initial** *NaN* cells (*ffill* has no previous value to
  take as source),
- without **trailing** *NaN* cells (whatever their number), just
  because of *last_valid_index*, terminating the action just
  before the trailing continuous sequence of *NaN*s,

but if you are happy with this arrangement, let it be.

I created the test DataFrame the following, more concise way:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'baz','foo'],  range(4)]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays, names=['first', 'second'])
np.random.seed(2)
arr = np.arange(1, 6 * 12 + 1, dtype=float).reshape(6, -1)
# Where to put NaN (x / y)
ind = (np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]),
       np.array([1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5,10, 2, 3,10,11]))
arr[ind] = np.nan
multi_ind = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols)
```

so that it contains:

```
first    bar                     baz                     foo                  
second     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
0        1.0   NaN   NaN   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
1       13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0   NaN  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
2       25.0   NaN  27.0   NaN  29.0   NaN  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  35.0  36.0
3       37.0  38.0  39.0  40.0  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0   NaN  48.0
4       49.0  50.0   NaN   NaN  53.0  54.0  55.0  56.0  57.0  58.0  59.0  60.0
5       61.0  62.0  63.0  64.0  65.0  66.0  67.0  68.0  69.0  70.0   NaN   NaN
```

To get your result, run:

```
result = multi_ind.stack(level=0).apply(
    lambda row: row[: row.last_valid_index() + 1].ffill(), axis=1)\
    .unstack(level=1).swaplevel(axis=1).reindex(columns=multi_ind.columns)
```

Note that your *last_valid_column_per_row* is not needed.
It is enough to pass *axis=1* to operate on rows, instead of
columns (like in the indicated post).

The result is:

```
first    bar                     baz                     foo                  
second     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
0        1.0   1.0   1.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
1       13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  18.0  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
2       25.0  25.0  27.0   NaN  29.0  29.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  35.0  36.0
3       37.0  38.0  39.0  40.0  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0  46.0  48.0
4       49.0  50.0   NaN   NaN  53.0  54.0  55.0  56.0  57.0  58.0  59.0  60.0
5       61.0  62.0  63.0  64.0  65.0  66.0  67.0  68.0  69.0  70.0   NaN   NaN
```

Details:

- `stack(level=0)` - put *bar*, *baz* and *foo* "fragments"
  in consecutive rows.
- `apply(….ffill(), axis=1)` - *fill* each row, without the trailing
  sequence of *NaN* (if any). Note that I added *+ 1* in order to
  include the last non-*NaN* value in the result. Otherwise the last
  column would have been dropped.
- `unstack(level=1)` - restore the previous ("wide") arangement,
  but unfortunately the order of column MultiIndex levels is reversed.
- `swaplevel(axis=1)` - restore the original order of column levels,
  but unfortunately the order of column names is wrong.
- `reindex(…)` - restore the original column order.