# Forward fill missing value except for the last known value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to forward fill the missing value for each user_id. However, I don't want the last value to fill forward. For example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'user_id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2','a2','a2','a2','a2','a2'], 
                     'month' : ['1/1/1995','2/1/1995','3/1/1995','4/1/1995','5/1/1995','6/1/1995',
                                '1/1/1995','2/1/1995','3/1/1995','4/1/1995','5/1/1995','6/1/1995'],
                     'values': [1,1,np.nan, 2,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2]})
```

The output I hope to have:

```
group   month   value
a   1/1/1995    1
a   2/1/1995    1
a   3/1/1995    1
a   4/1/1995    2
a   5/1/1995    
a   6/1/1995    
b   1/1/1995    1
b   2/1/1995    1
b   3/1/1995    1
b   4/1/1995    1
b   5/1/1995    1
b   6/1/1995    2
```

The last two months of group a were not filled because the value of this group stops on 04/01/1995.

I tried to use the generalized forward fill function:

```
data2 = data.fillna(method="ffill")
```

But it fills all missing values

I also tried the `last_valid_index` [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388419/forward-fill-all-except-last-value-in-python-pandas-dataframe):

```
data.apply(lambda series: series.loc[:series.last_valid_index()].ffill())
```

It also fills all missing values in my case

Answer (score -1):

You can `ffill` everything, but then use `mask` to turn back to `NaN` any null values past the last non-null value within a group.

We form groups of consecutive nulls (within 'user_id') with a `cumsum`, then find the last set of nulls with a `transform` + `max` and also making sure it's a null value.

```
s = data['values'].notnull().groupby(data['user_id']).cumsum()
s = (s == s.groupby(data['user_id']).transform('max')) & data['values'].isnull()

data['values'] = data['values'].ffill().mask(s)
```

---

```
print(data)

   user_id     month  values
0       a1  1/1/1995     1.0
1       a1  2/1/1995     1.0
2       a1  3/1/1995     1.0
3       a1  4/1/1995     2.0
4       a1  5/1/1995     NaN
5       a1  6/1/1995     NaN
6       a2  1/1/1995     1.0
7       a2  2/1/1995     1.0
8       a2  3/1/1995     1.0
9       a2  4/1/1995     1.0
10      a2  5/1/1995     1.0
11      a2  6/1/1995     2.0
```

Comment: `data.groupby("user_id")["values"].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().mask(x.bfill().isna()))`

Comment: @d.b Yes you can do that, but for many groups the `groupby.apply` will slow significantly. The above is more complicated, but because it only uses the built-in aggregations and avoids an apply it will work very well for large data.